# How to efficiently find minimum distance away from an obstacle given a start and end point in a grid

Tags: python, matrix, path, maze

Given a grid ('.' represents positions that we can move to, '*' represents obstacles, 's' and 'e' represent the start and end point in the grid), and a start point and end point, I need to find the minimum distance that I will be away from an obstacle. An optimal path will be to move in a manner that maximizes the distance away from any obstacle. If there is no path from the start to the end point, then 0 will be returned. Else, if there is a path for example, then if the closest I ever get to an obstacle is 2 Manhatten distances away from an obstacle in the grid, I will return 2. 2 will be the minimum distance I will be to the obstacle given an optimal path that tries to maximize the distance from all obstacles. I have tried to use DP to first calculate the distance to the closest obstacle for each point on the grid, and then run BFS with a priority queue from the start to end point. Yet I have still been facing Time Limit Exceeded for this problem. How else can I optimize it?

Example Input:

```
5
..*
.S.
..*
...
..E
```

Answer: 2
The closest we ever get to an obstacle is 2. The ideal path to take is (1,1) -> (1,0) -> (2,0) -> (3,0) -> (4,0) -> (4,1) -> (4,2)

My Code:

```
from collections import deque
from queue import PriorityQueue
  
def findMaximumDistance(grid):
    # # Write your code here
    matrix = []
    new_matrix = []
    for row in grid: 
        matrix.append(list(row))
        row = [1 if ele != '*' else 0 for ele in row]
        new_matrix.append(list(row))

    # Mark starting point
    m, n = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            if matrix[i][j] == 'S':
                start = (i,j)
            elif matrix[i][j]== 'E':
                end = (i,j)

def updateMatrix(mat):
        m, n = len(mat), len(mat[0])

        for r in range(m):
            for c in range(n):
                if mat[r][c] > 0:
                    top = mat[r - 1][c] if r > 0 else math.inf
                    left = mat[r][c - 1] if c > 0 else math.inf
                    mat[r][c] = min(top, left) + 1

        for r in range(m - 1, -1, -1):
            for c in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
                if mat[r][c] > 0:
                    bottom = mat[r + 1][c] if r < m - 1 else math.inf
                    right = mat[r][c + 1] if c < n - 1 else math.inf
                    mat[r][c] = min(mat[r][c], bottom + 1, right + 1)

        return mat

new_matrix = updateMatrix(new_matrix)

def best_first_search(start, end):
        nonlocal min_dist, visited
        DIR = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
        pq = PriorityQueue()
        pq.put((-new_matrix[start[0]][start[1]], start))
        
        while pq:
            dist, pos = pq.get()
            dist = -dist
            # update min_dist
            r, c = pos
            min_dist = min(min_dist, dist)
            visited.append((r,c))
            if pos == end:
                break
            for i in range(4):
                nr, nc = r + DIR[i], c + DIR[i + 1]
                if nr < 0 or nr == m or nc < 0 or nc == n or (nr,nc) in visited: continue
                pq.put((-new_matrix[nr][nc],(nr, nc)))
    
visited = []            
min_dist = float('inf')    
best_first_search(start, end)
return min_dist
```

Comment: Add the code that you are using.

Comment: where do you get `Time Limit Exceeded`? Is this task from some page with challenges? You could add link in question (not in comments)

Comment: @DanNagle I have updated my code thus far in the question